# how to install pytorch with cuda on WSL2 without libcuda.so error

Tags: pytorch

I followed the instructions on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

as advised, but I get this error: `Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution can be found here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5663#issuecomment-1068499676 by following these steps:

Run a command line shell as Administrator, type "cmd" to get a non-powershell command line.

Then type the following commands to create the problematic symbolic links:

C:
cd \Windows\System32\lxss\lib
del libcuda.so
del libcuda.so.1
mklink libcuda.so libcuda.so.1.1
mklink libcuda.so.1 libcuda.so.1.1

when you're done, it will look like this:

C:\Windows\System32\lxss\lib> DIR
... ...
Directory of C:\Windows\System32\lxss\lib
03/15/2022 04:00 PM

.
03/15/2022 03:59 PM libcuda.so [libcuda.so.1.1]
03/15/2022 04:00 PM libcuda.so.1 [libcuda.so.1.1]